# Determine if one Instant is the day after another Instant, factoring in timezone

Tags: java, java-time

Timestamps will be stored in a database. What is a solution to determine whether one timestamp, called "b", is the day after another timestamp, called "a"?

A timezone will be supplied as an argument.

For instance, consider:

```
Instant a = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1511928000L); // 11/29/17 4 AM
Instant b = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1511935200L); // 11/29/17 6 AM
```

If the user wants to know whether b is the day after a in the Eastern timezone (-5 hours), the program will compare:

Instant a at 11/28/17 11 PM and Instant b at 11/29/17 1 AM, and determine that b is the day after a.

Comment: Create ZonedDateTime s, then compare the dates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant a = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1511928000L); // 11/29/17 4 AM
    Instant b = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1511935200L); // 11/29/17 6 AM
    ZoneId localZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York"); // Can be any zone ID

    if (isBOneDayAfterA(a, b, localZone)) {
        System.out.println("b is one day after a!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("b is NOT one day after a");
    }
}

public static boolean isBOneDayAfterA(Instant a, Instant b, ZoneId localZone) {
    LocalDateTime aAdjusted = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(a, localZone);
    LocalDateTime bAdjusted = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(b, localZone);
    LocalDate aDate = aAdjusted.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate bDate = bAdjusted.toLocalDate();

    return bDate.minusDays(1).equals(aDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct zone id can be gotten with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.
That is usefull, for daytime saving which is country specific.

Besides ZonedDateTime also the following is possible:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC-5h");
OffsetDateTime ad = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(a, zoneId);
OffsetDateTime bd = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(b, zoneId);
return ad.getDayOfYear() != bd.getDayOfYear();
```

---

After comment a better solution - for the same day of year in different years:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC-5h");
ZonedDateTime ad = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(a, zoneId).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
ZonedDateTime bd = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(b, zoneId).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
return !ad.equals(bd);
```

Comment: Just comparing the day of year is fragile if you may happen to compare, say, November 28 last year with November 28 this year.

Comment: @OleV.V. The question was about day limits, but you are right; extended the answer, but the OP's own answer, simply LocalDate+ZoneId seems more appropriate. I confess that I did not trust LocalDate here.